# Javascript: Remove Hyphens

Tags: javascript

So I have been working on this function but I can't figure out how to remove the remainder hyphens at the end of the string.

```
function solution(s) {
  var l = s.length,
  max = l - (l % 3 ? ((l + 1) % 3 ? 4 : 2) : 0);
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < max; i+=3) {
    result += s.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').slice(i, i + 3) + "-";
  }
  for(var i = max; i < l; i+=2) {
    result += s.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '').slice(i, i + 2) + "-";
 }
   return result.slice(0,-1);
 }

  console.log(solution("0 - 22 1985--324"));
  console.log(solution("555372654"));
```

I know that "result.slice(0,-1)" should've fixed the issue but it just removes one hyphen at the end.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Could you add a simple `Input: <value>` - `Expected Output: <value>` example? It is not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: you can use regex to do that: `result.replace(/\-$/, '')`

Comment: Input: 0 - 22 1985--324 Expected Output: 022-198-532-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return /.*[^-]/.exec(result)[0]
```